# Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory error in Colab Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm Hadoop in Colab and I have two documents that I've made in Pycharm, one with the mapper and another one with the reducer part.

This is the code:

```
!apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null

!wget https://downloads.apache.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.3.3/hadoop-3.3.3.tar.gz

!tar -xzf hadoop-3.3.3.tar.gz
!mv hadoop-3.3.3/ /usr/local/

import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["HADOOP_HOME"] = "/usr/local/hadoop-3.3.3"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/usr/local/hadoop-3.3.3/bin" 

!chmod u+x ./mapperModaGastoPorPersona.py
!chmod u+x ./reducerModaGastoPorPersona.py

!hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.3.3.jar -file ./mapperModaGastoPorPersona.py -mapper ./mapperModaGastoPorPersona.py -file ./reducerModaGastoPorPersona.py -reducer ./reducerModaGastoPorPersona.py -input Datos_actividad_1.txt -output ./salidaModaGastoPersona1
```

And the result in the last part is this:

```
2022-12-14 12:18:36,116 ERROR streaming.PipeMapRed: configuration exception
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/content/./reducerModaGastoPorPersona.py": error=2, No such file or directory
    (...)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    (...)
2022-12-14 12:18:36,119 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce task executor complete.
2022-12-14 12:18:36,122 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local520054471_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:559)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:347)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.configure(PipeReducer.java:67)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/content/./reducerModaGastoPorPersona.py": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 18 more
2022-12-14 12:18:36,777 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local520054471_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
2022-12-14 12:18:36,794 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=4175
        FILE: Number of bytes written=644002
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=102
        Map output records=102
        Map output bytes=869
        Map output materialized bytes=1079
        Input split bytes=87
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=0
        Reduce shuffle bytes=1079
        Reduce input records=0
        Reduce output records=0
        Spilled Records=102
        Shuffled Maps =1
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=1
        GC time elapsed (ms)=0
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=350224384
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=969
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=0
2022-12-14 12:18:36,801 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful!
Streaming Command Failed!
```

I've uploaded the documents "mapperModaGastoPorPersona.py", "reducerModaGastoPorPersona.py" and "Datos_actividad_1.txt" in Colab.

Comment: Error seems self descriptive. The reducer file wasn't uploaded correctly, or you've mistyped its name. Also, no one really writes mapreduce code anymore. Have you considered using Pyspark instead, where you don't  even need to install Hadoop?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Although Hadoop installation is not mandatory, it is required in some cases, as stated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832217/do-i-need-to-install-hadoop-in-order-to-use-all-aspects-of-pyspark#:~:text=PySpark%20is%20Python%20API%20on,%2FHive%2FHBase%20or%20Both.

Comment: @Lad YARN clusters cannot be installed in Google colab since they're single instances. Therefore, local master is all that's possible, and no point running a different scheduler without a cluster. If wanting a cluster, that'd be possible with Dataproc

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the clarification. Then I completely agree with your previous comment.